# how to subscribe to eventstream - serverside

Tags: javascript, node.js, streaming, eventsource

I have a url that return `text/event-stream` data so I am trying to connect and print everything I find:

```
var url = "..."
var source = new EventSource(url);

source.addEventListener('message', function(e) { 
    console.log(e.data);
}, false);

source.addEventListener('open', function(e) { }, false);

source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {  }
}, false);
```

unfortunately this doesn't work serverside.  can I connect this way?

```
$ node app.js

app.js:2
var source = new EventSource(url);
                 ^

ReferenceError: EventSource is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you forgot on server side :

```
var EventSource = require("eventsource");
```